# Java publish safely with final

Tags: java, multithreading, visibility

just to make sure. 
I am following the Java Concurrency in practice book.
When it comes to publish safely especially with final, it is clear to me that firstly the reference will be visible to all other threads and secondly the state of the published object is visible to any other thread but the question here is if the state of the referenced array elements is guaranteed to be visible with the state it was published? (surely as long no one modifies those data objects).

Example:

```
@Mutable
public class NotThreadsafeDataObject {

    private String message;

    public NotThreadsafeDataObject (String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

}
```

Now let's publish safely an array of mutable objects:

```
public class Publish {

    public final NotThreadsafeDataObject[] publish;

    public Publish() {
        publish = new NotThreadsafeDataObject[] { new NotThreadsafeDataObject("one"), new NotThreadsafeDataObject("two")};

    }

}
```

Comment: As I understand it final indicates that (for objects) the reference will not change. However, the internal state of that object may still change and the threads are still permitted to take their own caches of these internals. The volatile keyword preventing threads keeping their own caches

Comment: The referenced object and its referenced objects are not changed after publish... let's say by convention. I want to know about the visibility of the referenced mutable objects inside the array after safe publish using a final field.

Answer (score 0):

If we speak in terms presented in "Java Concurrency in Practice" then your array is an "effectively immutable" object. For such objects safe publication is always necessary for not corrupting the internal state. So your code is OK, because you are using safe publication. More specifically the "final" keyword memory semantics guarantees that a thread accessing the final field will see everything that happened before the field was written ("happen-before" is established).

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure that you can still modify the values of your individual mutable objects in your Array. I.e.

```
publish[0].setMessaage("Hello");
```

would work just fine. And also I believe you can remove objects from your array. It's the Array reference that can not be changed because it is declared `final`. If you want to have completely immutable collection I would work with List that is declared as final and then create a new separate List, populate it and then use method [public static  List unmodifiableList(List list)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableList(java.util.List)) to assig it to your final list:

```
ublic class Publish {

    public static final List<NotThreadsafeDataObject> publish;

    static {
        init();
    }  

    private static void synchronized init() {
       List<NotThreadsafeDataObject> list = new ArrayList<>();
       list.add(new NotThreadsafeDataObject("one");
       list.add(new NotThreadsafeDataObject("two");
       publish = Collections.unmodifiableList(list);
    }  
}
```

This makes bulletproof completely immutable list that neither reference to it nor its contents could be changed.